# "Parallel Execution Issue: Inconsistent Web Element Visibility and Accessibility, Timeout Errors Occurring"

Tags: cross-browser, ui-automation, playwright-java, parallel-execution

Whenever I try to run the script in a single browser, the web elements are visible and accessible. However, during parallel execution, there was an issue where one browser frequently failed to locate the web element, this was not due to a single element, rather, several elements appeared at different locations on each run. Most of the time, a timeout message was displayed on the console .

Error:com.microsoft.playwright.TimeoutError: Error {  message='Timeout 30000ms exceeded.}

I've tried to fix the problem by adding the waitfortimeout method where the error is occurring, but occasionally my web element gets clicked while the waitfortimeout method is functioning well.Sometimes it isn't. I was hoping for a fix for the cross-browser parallel execution problem I was facing; I was seeking an efficient method that would allow me to run the script consistently.